# Change host or server name in Meteor for accounts-ui / accounts-google

Tags: dns, meteor, user-accounts

I'm building my first Meteor app, and when configuring accounts-ui / accounts-google I'm prompted to `Set Authorized Redirect URI to: http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close` -- but that is not the URL of my server and if I set that, it does not receive the redirect from the google login.

However, I cannot find out how tell meteor (or the accounts-ui) the correct hostname of the server, so the accounts-ui popup keeps saying to use localhost as the server name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable `ROOT_URL`. http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl:

> The server reads from the ROOT_URL environment variable to determine
>   where it is running. This is taken care of automatically for apps
>   deployed with meteor deploy, but must be provided when using meteor
>   bundle.

on a posix system (linux, osx) you can just start meteor like this:

```
env ROOT_URL=http://myserver.com:myport meteor
```

Comment: Just to be redundant for confused readers like myself, the environment specifically refers to the shell environment, such as bash or csh, that meteor is being run in.